# Python Classes (object) and Functions (self) in C#

Tags: c#, python, function, class

I'm currently building my own interpreter for a custom language using C#. I'm currently following this guide (https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/) which I think would help me make my simple interpreter. However, the guide has code for Python, and I don't know a single thing in Python.

I'm having trouble with this bit of code in the guide:

```
INTEGER, PLUS, EOF = 'INTEGER', 'PLUS', 'EOF'
class Token(object):
def __init__(self, type, value):
    # token type: INTEGER, PLUS, or EOF
    self.type = type
    # token value: 0, 1, 2. 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, '+', or None
    self.value = value

def __str__(self):
    """String representation of the class instance.

    Examples:
        Token(INTEGER, 3)
        Token(PLUS '+')
    """
    return 'Token({type}, {value})'.format(
        type=self.type,
        value=repr(self.value)
    )

def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()
```

I assume that `INTEGER`, `PLUS`, and `EOF` are global constants. But in my code I can't create something similar to this, so I just create the constant in the function where I need it like `const string INTEGER = "INTEGER"`. Is this correct?

Second problem: I can't figure out how classes and functions work in Python. From the code above, I created this in C#:

```
public class Token {
    public string tokenStr(string type, string value)
    {
        return "Token(" + type + "," + value + ")";
    }
}
```

I don't  understand what `object` in the parenthesis means in the Python Class, also the `self` in the parenthesis on the Python function. I also don't know where to put the `__init__` function in C#.

Can someone teach me what the Python code means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, these are global vars. Your approach is just fine.
The 'object' in the parentheses is an inheritance from the class 'object'. As far as you care in this case, you can ignore it.
The self in the parentheses is just python syntax, self is the equivalent for 'this' in C#, and you have to specify it in the method's signature. Again, you can ignore it.
**init** is simply the constructor of the class.

Comment: So if `init` is the default constructor, it means in C# that that's where I put my get/set for the `type` and `value` fields? Python seems to not specify what data type will be returned, because later on in the code in the guide there will be a code like `return Token(EOF, None)` which I assume returns an instance of Token. In Python, is this code a method or a constructor?

Comment: Nevermind, I got everything working. Had I not known that `object` and `self` should be ignored, I wouldn't have done the Python to C# conversion successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Great, good luck! Python is a dynamic typing language indeed, so you can set/return any type.